# HTTP 456 when using Headless Chrome

Tags: http, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to navigate to https://my.waveapps.com using headless chrome, and getting a 456 Access denied.

I have no idea why.

Navigating to the same url with the exact same chromium binary in normal mode works fine. Only adding the `--headless` option breaks it.

I am using Chromium 66.0.3333.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things to do to avoid Headless Chrome being detected:

- change user agent
- if you are using it through `chromedriver`, for example by using Selenium, then you also need to patch the `chromedriver` executable

### Changing user agent

When used in headless mode, Chrome change its user agent, turning `Chrome` into `HeadlessChrome`, as a result it is easily detectable for anyone who wants to deny headless browsers.

So be sure to change user agent to look like a normal browser, for example:

```
chrome \
    --disable-gpu \
    --headless \
    --remote-debugging-port=9222 \
    --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36' \
    'https://my.waveapps.com/login/'
```

### Patching chromedriver

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41220267/2873507), the website you are trying to reach uses Distil Networks to detect headless browsers, and to avoid being detected you need to remove any "cdc_" string from the chromedriver executable, by running the following command:

```
perl -pi -e 's/cdc_/aaa_/g' /path/to/chromedriver
```

Replace `aaa` by any three character combination you like.

Seems to work for me:
[image: my.waveapps.com]

Comment: Thank you VERY much for the reply !
I have tried it, and while I got it to work in some cases, I couldn't get it to work reliably : I had to clear cookies for it to work, and still, some workflows don't work. For example, if I run it, clear cookies, reload, it works. Then if I quit chromium, and relaunch it, then it first appears as Access Denied, and I have to clear cookies again for it to work. Using chromedriver and Selenium, clearing cookies before starting it doesn't get it to work. Any idea ?

Comment: Actually I am getting it to work pretty reliably manually. It seems to go wrong when I go through Chromedriver. I checked user agent by `System.out.println("user agent : " + (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return navigator.userAgent;"));` and it prints the updated value indeed, so the problem seems to be somewhere else. Any idea ?

Comment: I am trying to troubleshoot the problem, but I am having a hard time understanding how to debug. I have set chromedriver to verbose mode, and looked at the logs, but it doesn't tell much more. Apparently this is due to the site using Distil to block bots, but I still can't find why it blocks only when using chromedriver

Comment: Maybe see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33403473/8512324. It says that Distil Networks' purpose is to block web-scraping...

Comment: thanks !! I had seen it, but hadn't taken enough time to go through it. I tried patching the chromedriver binary and it worked. Thank you so much for your help !